# Python, Flask, Twitter and UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, flask

I am working with Python and Flask utilizing the Twitter API. I request some data from Twitter that comes with special characters like 'ñ' and so on, for example a list with the trending topics.

The problem comes when trying to display correctly those characters. I thought the universal solution for these kind of issues was to apply the `unquote()` and `encode(utf-8)` methods, like this:

```
new_string = urllib.unquote(old_string).decode('utf-8')
```

However, when working with Flask, when trying to apply the `unquote()` function to my data I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have been reading similar cases here on stack overflow but haven't managed to come up with  the correct way to show the data with the right characters on my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
new_string = urllib.unquote(unicode(old_string))
```

Comment: Well with your code, at least, now it doesn't give an error, but characters like 'ñ' are displayed incorrectly as 'Ã±' for example.

Comment: I use `unicode()` function for Persian locale, set your file to utf-8 , put after shebang line : `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`